# How to completely start from scratch with Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, asus, reset

I have an ASUS notebook and it comes from factory with Ubuntu. I like Ubuntu and I do not want to change the OS. However, this notebook does not have a disc drive. It does have USB, but I do not know how to boot from USB. I'd like to wipe the computer entirely.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would download a Live USB of the version of Ubuntu you want to use. This tells you how to do it: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

On my Asus Ultrabook I'm able to press esc during the boot process and select an alternative boot device.

Start from a a cold boot, insert the Live USB and hit escape while it's booting. It might require multiple presses. Then choose the USB devices to boot from. Ubuntu should start up. Once it's in the desktop, just choose "Install." During the setup sequence it will detect what's already there and give you the option to overwrite it.